# Chirp zero crossings

Tags: audio, chirp

I am generating a linear chirp in C code with a f0 , f1 and T. What is the most efficient way to solve where the zero crossings appear?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that T is the length of the chirp, a linear chirp is given by

$$x(t) = \sin\left[2\pi  \cdot \left(  t\cdot f_1+ \frac{t^2}{2T}(f_2-f_1)\right)\right] $$

A zero crossing occurs when the phase is an integer multiple of $\pi$, so we can determine the $k^{th}$ zero crossing is given by the relationship

$$ t_k\cdot f_1+ \frac{t_k^2}{2T}(f_2-f_1) = k/2$$

This is a quadratic equation that can be solved to determine $t_k$.

Comment: Hi Hilmar thank you for that answer.  Say I wanted to make my chirp independent of sampling frequency knowing tk would become a problem?

Comment: @DeveloperR I don't understand that question! Sampling rate doesn't appear anywhere here, this is all continuous-time signals.

Comment: Ok Marcus what I mean is if I don't know tk then I can't solve for the kth crossing

Comment: @DeveloperR you don't seem to understand the formula then: $t_k$ is the time at which the $k$th zero crossing takes place. You literally solve for $t_k$.

Comment: @DeveloperR: what exactly do you mean by "solving for the kth zero crossing". The answer allows to calculate the time at which the zero crossing occurs for any value of k. Is there something else you want or need ?

Comment: Floor function.

Comment: wait. @DeveloperR is it possible you forgot how to solve quadratic equations? It might be that us DSP'lers just see a quadratic function like that and say "yeah, the roots of that can easily be found" and move on, because it's math, and we basically do that all day long, but it might be a long way back for you; so please don't take offense in that case: The equation Hilmar gave you allows you to find $t_k$.